Changing netplan Subnet mask on Ubuntu Server makes server unreachable
I am trying to widen the subnet on an Ubuntu server (also runs DHCP) so I can put my IoT devices on a different subnet - I currently use 192.168.1.x - I want to put the devices on 192.168.2.x and 192.168.3.x.
I altered the /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml file (this was presumably built by the wizard when I installed Ubuntu):
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      addresses:
      - 192.168.1.14/24
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 8.8.8.8
        search: []
      routes:
      - to: default
        via: 192.168.1.1
  version: 2

to change the line to
    eno1:
      addresses:
      - 192.168.1.14/22

however when I try sudo netplan try (other than expected warnings about ovsdb-server.service not running and the netplan file being too accessible) the system becomes unreachable and I need to log in on the box itself and revert the change - what am I doing wrong please?
the DHCP file /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf which supplies the IP address for the machine I am connecting to the server from has:
default-lease-time 86400;
max-lease-time 86400;
authoritative;
 
subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
 range 192.168.1.100 192.168.1.200;
 option routers 192.168.1.1;
 option domain-name-servers 192.168.1.14;
}

laptop ip config if relevant:
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::7e7c:9bd5:64cd:ded6%5(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.107(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : 19 April 2024 09:30:14
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : 20 April 2024 09:30:12
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.14
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 89686696
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-28-09-32-12-F0-6E-0B-D9-52-D4
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.14

I realise for me to see the other subnets I would need to change the mask in DHCP but surely I should be able to see the server?
I didn't think this should be an issue as I am not changing the IP address of the server, nor of my laptop.
thanks
